# php mysql select count from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in Mysql

Table1: item(itemNO, type,name)
Table2: remark (itemNO, content)

I use while for viewing the data of item

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM item WHERE NO ='$NO' ORDER BY rand()  LIMIT 5";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$row['itemNO'];
$row['Type'];
$row['name'];

}
```

I want to show count of the remark(s) for the item which share same itemNO in two tables.
I tried to create new query in while for counting the remark for the item but fail.

What I should do for showing the count of remark in while?

Comment: read about mysql join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could be done in 1 query:

```
SELECT item.itemNO, item.type, item.name,
       COUNT(*) AS totalRemarks
FROM item
LEFT JOIN remark ON remark.itemNO = item.itemNO
GROUP BY item.itemNO, item.type, item.name
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 5
```

Left join, as you probably want to see items with no remarks as well

I notice a flaw: in case of no remarks, it will still mention "1"

this change could solve it:

```
SELECT item.itemNO, item.type, item.name,
       COUNT(remark.itemNO) AS totalRemarks
FROM item
LEFT JOIN remark ON remark.itemNO = item.itemNO
GROUP BY item.itemNO, item.type, item.name
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I tried your code, but not work, and unable to show the data in while for loop.

Comment: but what if you try it directly on the database (phpmyadmin for example). --is it a problem with the query, or with the executing php-code?

Answer (score 0):

Use join for this. try this query

```
$sql="SELECT count(itemNO) as totalItem FROM item i inner join remark r on r.itemNO = i.itemNO";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use
  INNER JOIN

```
$sql="SELECT count(*) FROM item INNER JOIN remark ON item.itemNO = remark.itemNo WHERE item.NO ='$NO'";
```

Answer (score 0):

No need multiple query . simple use `JOIN and GROUP BY CLAUSE`

```
 select i.* ,r.*,count(r.itemNO) as remark_count 
 from item as i 
 left join remark as r 
 on (i.itemNO=r.itemNO) 
 WHERE i.itemNO='$No'
 group by i.itemNO
```